# django-celery: bind=True fails, takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am trying to retry a celery task if it fails. This is my task,

```
@shared_task(queue='es', bind=True, max_retries=3)
def update_station_es_index(doc_id, doc_body):
    """
    Celery consumer method for updating ES.
    """
    try:
        #es_client is connecting to ElasticSearch
        es_client.update_stations(id=doc_id, body=doc_body)
    except Exception as e:
        self.retry(exc=e)
```

But I get this error when this task is called,

```
TypeError: update_station_es_index() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have not found enough help on the web for this error, just [this github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3222), but that does not explain much.

Can anyone tell me what is happening and what is the solution here?

Using Django2.0.5 and celery4.2.0

Answer (score 27):

You must add `self` as an argument. When you specify `bind=True`, the task itself will be passed as the first argument.

Suppose you have a standard task `add` which takes two arguments

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

If you specify `bind=True` on this task, it will need to accept another argument.

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    # ...
```

So change

```
def update_station_es_index(doc_id, doc_body):
```

to

```
def update_station_es_index(self, doc_id, doc_body):
```

Comment: saved my derrier again.

Comment: what is the better option `(bind=True)` or without it

Comment: @TalhaAnwar it is situational... use `bind=True` when you need a reference to the task object. If you don't need to reference the task, then it's OK to omit `bind=True`.